# ¿Sumar una cantidad input de números con JavaScript mediante el comando for?

Tags: javascript

"Escribe un programa que pregunte cuantos números vas a introducir, pida esos números y calcule su suma" ¿Cómo haría esto con JavaScript? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho esto pero no sé como sumar todos los sumandos que me quedan dentro del for.

Comment: Favor de leer [ask], la idea de la comunidad es apoyar en dudas claras de programación, no es hacer tareas; deveras editar esto y colocar que llevas hecho o investigadov

Comment: Vale, perdona. He subido una captura con lo que llevo hecho. ^^

Comment: Deberías subir el código y no una imagen del código. En el for tienes que guardar el sumando: total = total + sumando.. sino retornas "total" que nunca le asignas un valor además del 0 inicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder sumar los números que vas introduciendo tienes que utilizar tu variable total.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<html>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var num = prompt("Cantidad de numeros: ");
    var sumando;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        sumando = prompt("Numeros: ");
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(sumando)
    }

    alert("Suma total: " + parseInt(total));
</script>

</html>
```

Tienes un fallo en tu ciclo `for`, estás separando con `,` cuando se debe separar con `;` como veras tambien he utilizado `parseInt()`, que sirve para **parsear** los números como enteros, para así hacer que la suma salga correcta y no con tus números concatenados.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!!! ^^ Llevaba trabado con esta tontería mas de una hora xD.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido mi respuesta. Vota positivo a mi respuesta y marca el check que esta debajo. Saludos.